# OS X alternative to Xcode OpenGL ES Error breakpoint

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

Xcode has a useful feature for OpenGL ES debugging (on iOS) allowing set an "OpenGL ES Error Breakpoint". What's the equivalent feature for OS X development?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Apple's Graphics Tools for Developers (`Xcode | Open Developer Tool | More Developer Tools...`)
2. Launch OpenGL Profiler
3. Go to `View | Breakpoints`
4. In the Breakpoints dialog, check `Break on OpenGL Error`
5. Launch your application through the OpenGL Profiler